# Creating mountains using multiple Position&Height&Slope data

Tags: mesh, terrain, procedural-generation

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out a way to solve my terrain generation problem.

I randomly generate bunch of height&slope values with a position.

Lets say these are my positions with height&slope values.

[Positions&Height&Slopes as Dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLElT.png)

with this set of data i need to smoothly interpolate the heights across the plane.

Result should look like this

[Example image(Black dots are the positions from the previous image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjzzM.png)

I tried several functions such as **Logistic**,**Gaussian** or simple **exponential** decay.Tried give different **weights** to the
position&height values depending on their location and height&slope,in the end i failed to create a mesh with a proper looking terrain.

I managed to create single mountains seperate from each other,but when it comes to creating an interpolating equation between these dots somehow i fail or overlook something.

One more thing,i create bunch of terrain chunks dynamically  to create and discard geometrical detail on the run,so im bound by the realtime performance metrics and cant offer an long computation time.

I welcome any kind of input.

Comment: Maybe look in to Bezier surface curves: https://www.sbgames.org/sbgames2019/files/papers/ComputacaoFull/198326.pdf